# Different number of Columns in rows of a table

Tags: javascript, html-table

Is it possible to create a table with different number of cells in each and every row with the same width and height ..?? If so how it can be done in a simpler way ..???

Note:

1. Row width and height are same
2. Cell width differs in each and every row

   ```
   <table>
   <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   ```

   [This](http://jsfiddle.net/4RM7S/1/) is what i have tried using coll span ..Here let's say first row cells width is 30px,30px,30px . if i use coll span , it will be like 60px,30px but i want it as 50px,40px with only 2 cells

I want like this[image]

Comment: Did you try something ? What was the problem ?

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding the problem.

Comment: yes. but you must have to know max no. of columns first. Then use column span

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `colspan` to create cells that span multiple columns.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RM7S/)

[image]

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you want all to be the same width and height but only have the number of cells differ you can just not style certain cells in the `<table>`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eRRD/)

[image]

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Update

Your update with the image, yes you can accomplish this using `colspan`:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RTU6e/)

[image]

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This uses four columns, the middle two are smaller than the others, here is an image that illustrates how the columns are set up:

[image]

### Update #2

Here is an example of more randomly sizes cells. The first row 10%, 90% and the second row 55%, 45%.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jAfY/1/)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    width:100px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height:1em;
}
tr:first-child td:first-child {
    width:10%;
}
tr:first-child td:last-child {
    width:90%;
}
tr:last-child td:first-child {
    width:55%;
}
tr:last-child td:last-child {
    width:45%;
}
```

Comment: What you have provided is " If first row has cells of 30px each then second row has cells of 45px each right "...?? But what i need is " it may be 10px and 80 px or 50px and 40px or soon  " .. Width of the row is same but width of the cell is different

Comment: You can set the columns to be whatever size you want using `width` in CSS. You cannot set a column's widths to different sizes, otherwise they will not be columns, you can only fake it with columns and `colspan`. What you're trying to do is actually quite bad as tables should only contain tabular data and you can achieve this so much more simply with plain `div`s.

Comment: so it's not possible to achieve it in a single table...??

Comment: How can we apply this CSS using Javascript...??

Comment: I wouldn't want to do it without jQuery `$('tr:last-child td:first-child').css('width', '50%');`

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('tr:last-child td:first-child')[0].style.width = '50%';`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, with the `colspan` attribute for table cells, like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td colspan="2">2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td colspan="5">2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td colspan="2">3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sk5cB/

Answer (score 0):

Not positive that this is what you're looking for, but you could create a table with merged cells by using the `colspan` attribute in your `<td>` tags.

[HTML  colspan Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use and create a table in

```
    <tr> </tr> tags
```

Comment: I need it in a single table

Comment: Yeah in a single table u can create another table in a table data

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to insert content in those cells and prefer to maintain the same cell width then it is impossible using only tables. I've searched for solutions on this problem as well, it looks great when the cells are empty like Daniel Imms presented in his example, but if you add content to those cells their width starts getting bigger and the other cells on the row start getting smaller. Specifying table-layout:fixed doesn't help because then the first row becomes the rule for all following rows.

If you have the possibility to use divs with float left and width in percentage and a clear fix display:table div that wraps them all, just like Bootstrap 3 does in its grid system, then that'll be much more reliable.